# possible ways to integrate python or r into apache superset to visualize and share data?

Tags: python, r, integration, visualization, apache-superset

Can any one help us out with leads to integrate either python or r with apache superset so as to extend the capabilities, we are trying to view the survival analysis in superset.

Comment: Hi stardust, welcome to Stack Overflow. This site focuses on *specific* **programming** questions. Yours isn't about a specific programming question, and thus isn't appropriate here. Your question will likely be closed as either opinion based or too broad. If you settle on an approach and run into problems, you can open a new question which includes your code.